# Uncaught TypeError when adding a trigger to jqModal

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I've got a jqModal dialog:

```
function initOrderIdCardDialog() {
    $('#orderIdCardDialog').jqm({
        trigger: '#orderIdCardButton',
        overlay: 85, /* 0-100 (int) : 0 is off/transparent, 100 is opaque */
        overlayClass: 'dialogOverlay',
        closeClass:'cancelOrderIDCard',
        onShow: showDialog,
        onHide: hideDialog,
        toTop: true
    });
}
```

that is called after some html:

```
<a href="#" class="sideBtn" id="orderIdCardButton">Order ID Card</a>
...
<div id="orderIdCardDialog" class="dialog">
    ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    initOrderIdCardDialog();
</script>
```

and when the page is loading, an exception is thrown in jqModal.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on line 34 of jqModal.js, just after:

```
$.fn.jqmAddTrigger=function(e){return hs(this,e,'jqmShow');};
```

As a result, clicking on the link does not show a dialog. If I replace the jQuery selector with an empty string for the trigger, the exception is not thrown. I'm a bit confused because [jqModal's site](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#how) says that a jQuery selector is valid. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, you included jqm script ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the header, I just verified again to make sure.

Comment: What's the version of jQuery? It doesn't work with 1.9+. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/ZJHJ4/). Change it to 1.8.3 in the fiddle and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [anpsmn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473016/anpsmn):

> What's the version of jQuery? It doesn't work with 1.9+. See fiddle. Change it to 1.8.3 in the fiddle and it works.